# Change Website Language and URL of Domain For a Specific Country

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, country-codes

I've a website with some static pages name **(www.ranglerz.com)**, what I'm trying is if a user will open our domain from **Belgium** than it will automatically redirect to **(www.ranglerz.be)** plus the language will change from **English to Dutch** as well.

I tried Google Automatic Language Translator + Domain Redirection but they did not work for me well. Is there any other solution I can implement? using .htaccess, javascript or anything else better for it

Answer (score 0):

you need to write some code that detects the coutry based on the client's ip.
this can either be done in javascript/client side (http://www.hostip.info/use.html for example) or on the server if your hosting service allows scripting (php).

try looking at geolocation frameworks ([here](http://www.geoplugin.com/)'s one)